# How to convert string with some "\r\n" into list?

Tags: c#, regex, string, linked-list

I have a string and want to convert it into a `LinkedList` such that every line is a single element.

I use Visual Studio 2012.

Is there any easy way to do it?

This string looks like:

```
LOAD  =5.01E+10
MPY   $1
ADD   $2
```

But in fact it contain `LOAD  =5.01E+10\r\nMPY   $1\r\nADD   $2`

IMPORTANT UPDATE: i don't need to remove "\r\n" or something like this. I need list (actually not linked) with pair of "left part" and "right part" in each element. Example of what kind of list i what to get from previous example:

```
("LOAD  ", "=5.01E+10") => ("MPY   ", "$1") => ("ADD   ", "$2") => null
```

Actually, better to save all this free space after left part.

Comment: In a *Windows* environment it's `\r\n`, on a *Linux*, it's `\n`.

Comment: Do you mean `var lines = myString.Split(new [] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();`

Comment: @InfernumDeus: what type do you use for the pars? `KeyValuePair`?

Comment: @CommuSoft, not sure if get what you are asking. I just need linked pair of 2 strings.

Comment: @InfernumDeus: yes I got that part, but how do you want to store such pairs? As a [`Tuple<string,string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`KeyValuePair<string,string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), dedicated type, other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So from your question, I get that you need this string to be transformed into a linked list - key, value pairs. Here is a way to do that:

**Edit** (sorry this question had too may edits):

```
string input = "LOAD  =5.01E+10\r\nMPY   $1\r\nADD   $2";

IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs =
    input.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(x => x.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x[0], x[1]));

var data = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(pairs);
```

**Edit**

Here is how you iterate over the linked list:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in data) {
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} - Value: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Or get a node and access its `Value`, which is the key-value pair:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string> p = data.First.Value;
string k = p.Key; // LOAD
string v = p.Value; // =5.01E+10
```

Comment: Yes, i must save order.

Comment: @InfernumDeus Here you go I've changed it to a `LinkedList` if I understood you correctly.

Comment: @CommuSoft Yeah, I must have missed that, fixed.

Comment: Looks great! So how can i get values of some element?

Answer (score 4):

The way newlines are represented can depend on the environment: *Linux* for instance uses `\n`.

To make things easier, you can use a `StringReader`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Lines (string text) { 
    string line;
    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(text)) {
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

For lazy evaluation to lines: this can be helpful in the future if you for instance have a huge file, and only need the to show the first 10 lines to a user.

And then call:

```
return new LinkedList<string>(Lines(text));
```

**EDIT:**

To obtain the pairs, you can introduce a new method:

A second method then can be used split items into pairs:

```
public static KeyValuePair<string,string> SplitToKeyValue(string text) {
    Regex p = new Regex(@"^(\w+)\s+(.*)$");
    Match m = p.Match(text);
    return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(m.Groups[1].Value,m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

And then create the `LinkedList` with:

```
return new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<string,string>>(Lines(text).Select(SplitToKeyValue));
```

**DEMO**

using *Mono's* `csharp` interactive shell:

```
$ csharp
Mono C# Shell, type "help;" for help

Enter statements below.
csharp> using System.IO;
csharp> using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
csharp> public static class Foo {
      >  
      > public static KeyValuePair<string,string> SplitToKeyValue(string text) {
      >     Regex p = new Regex(@"^(\w+)\s+(.*)$");
      >     Match m = p.Match(text);
      >     return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(m.Groups[1].Value,m.Groups[2].Value);
      > }
      >  
      > public static IEnumerable<string> Lines (string text) { 
      >     string line;
      >     using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(text)) {
      >         while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
      >             yield return line;
      >         }
      >     }
      > }
      >  
      > }
csharp> string inp = "LOAD =5.01E+10\nMPY $1\nADD $2";
csharp> new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<string,string>>(Foo.Lines(inp).Select(Foo.SplitToKeyValue)) 
{ [LOAD, =5.01E+10], [MPY, $1], [ADD, $2] }
```

or [**fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TcL4oe).

Comment: Great to go the route for lazy evaluation

Comment: @paulroho: not only because of the lazyiness. `IEnumerable<T>` also enforces people to think more *declarative*, a mindset that is said to be more safe... ;).

Comment: If you want to put easily runable demos go try https://dotnetfiddle.net/ it is a web frontend for a mono C# shell and lets you have direct runnable links to the programs you write. Its great for answers on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
 yourString = yourString.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "\r\n");
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/newline

Comment: The problem with this question, is that in the real problem is only specified in the title...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output

```
string LOAD = "5.01E+10\r\nMPY $1\r\nADD $2";
string newstring1 = LOAD.Replace("\r", " ");
string newstring2 = newstring1.Replace("\n", " ");
Console.WriteLine(newstring2);
```

output

```
5.01E+10 MPY $1 ADD $2
```

Answer (score 0):

i understand as you need to convert string to list. if it right then solution is

```
 Regex.Matches("your string","\r\n", RegexOptions.Singleline|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```